# individual check box not working in react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Individual select box not working some times and it works fine on when I do build an application in another system is it code change issue or version issue works on group select

```
class Checkbox extends BaseComponent{
      constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this._bind('handleCheck');
        this.state = {
          checked: this.props.initialValue
        };
      }
    
      handleCheck(){
        this.setState({checked: !this.state.checked}, () => {
          this.props.onChange(this.state.checked);
        });
      }
    
    
      render(){
        const {labelCss} = this.props;
        const divCss = 'checkbox';
        return (
          <div className={divCss}>
            <input
              id={this.props.id}
              type='checkbox'
              onChange={this.handleCheck}
              defaultChecked={this.state.checked}
            />
            <label
              htmlFor={this.props.id}
              className={classNames('aria-label', labelCss)}>
              {this.props.labelText}
            </label>
    
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: Can you describe what's not working? I think we need more infos here to help you

Comment: I think you should use `value` with `onChange` (controlled input) instead of using `defaultChecked` (uncontrolled input).See more here: https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html

Answer (score 0):

I think that the error appears in this line:

```
this.setState({checked: !this.state.checked}, () => {
    this.props.onChange(this.state.checked);
});
```

You could try doing this

```
this.setState(prevState => ({checked: !prevState.checked}), () => {
    this.props.onChange(this.state.checked);
});
```

The problem is because React states updates can be asynchronous (https://es.reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous)

You also need to use the value prop in the input. `value={this.state.checked}`